# Mean, Median, Mode Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization, ggplotly

I have a below df like this.

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("UK", "US", "UK", "US", "UK", "US"),
              tcs = c(1205, 15002, 13455, 15012, 14015, 15012),
              cts = c(2300, 26004, 25000, 29004, 27500, 31004), 
              year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018))
```

If I find mean for tcs and cts, I get below result.

```
> mean(df$tcs)
[1] 12283.5
mean(df$cts)
[1] 23468.67
```

However, is there any function in R to plot them in a chart like bar, density, etc. to find mean, mode and median for the above df?

Comment: Have you actually tried using any of those libraries you've tagged to make your plot?

Comment: `summary(df)` or `skimr::skim(df)` are pretty handy for finding those numbers directly. There are also packages which make a whole report with charts etc., like  `DataExplorer::create_report(df)`

Comment: https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2018/01/02/my-favourite-r-package-for-summarising-data/

Answer (score -1):

I would probably write codes like this.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(tcs_mean = mean(tcs),
            cts_mean = mean(cts)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -country) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(country, value, fill = key)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2")
```

It would generate plot like this.

[image]

I used `summarise()` to generate new columns to show variables such as mean. Then `gather()` to convert data set tidy.

Comment: please include the package name you used for this plot

Comment: `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you used some more

Comment: then try `library(tidyverse)`